# Getting the collection name in AngularJS ngRepeat directive

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

If I have, for example, the array:

```
$scope.users = [
    John: {
        age: 18,
        genre: 'male',
        type: 'admin'
    },
    Paul: {
        age: 22,
        genre: 'male',
        type: 'admin'
    }
];
```

How can I get the users names when I iterate with ngRepeat?

```
<li ng-repeat="user in users">
   {{ }} <!-- Name Here --> 
   {{ user.age }} <br>
   {{ user.genre }} <br>
   {{ user.type }}
</li>
```

Thanks!

Comment: FYI, that's an invalid JSON array!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) You have error in your code: your array should be an object, since it has keys `John, Paul ...`

2) In [`ngRepeat`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat) you can [iterate over object properties like `(key, value) in obj`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat#iterating-over-object-properties)

Here is working example:

```js
angular.module('myApp', [])
.controller('MyCtrl', ['$scope', function MyCtrl($scope ) {
  var ctrl = this;
  
  ctrl.users =  {
      John: {
          age: 18,
          genre: 'male',
          type: 'admin'
      },
      Paul: {
          age: 22,
          genre: 'male',
          type: 'admin'
      }
  };
 
  
}]);
```

```html
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//code.angularjs.org/1.6.2/angular.js"></script>

<div ng-app="myApp">
  <div ng-controller="MyCtrl as $ctrl">  
   <ul>
      <li ng-repeat="(key, user) in $ctrl.users track by $index">
       {{ key }}
       {{ user.age }} <br>
       {{ user.genre }} <br>
       {{ user.type }}
      </li> 
   </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all arrays can't have custom keys. So I suppose you are using object $scope.users.

And for answer, you can do this: *ng-repeat="(name, user) in users"*

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat#iterating-over-object-properties

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Object.keys(users)` to get an array with the values ['Paul','John']

```
<li ng-repeat="user in users track by $index">
   {{ Object.keys(users)[$index] }}  
   {{ user.age }} <br>
   {{ user.genre }} <br>
   {{ user.type }}
</li>
```

this isn't tested but I think it should be along the lines of what you need.